# Haystack and Elasticsearch: partial word search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search-engine, django-haystack

- Django 1.8
- elasticsearch-2.3.1

**settings.py**

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
},
}
```

**search_indexes.html**

```
class VehicleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
garage = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='garage')
plate_number = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='plate_number')
chassis_number = indexes.CharField(model_attr='chassis_number')
brand = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='brand')
model = indexes.CharField(model_attr='model')

def get_model(self):
    return Vehicle

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

**Example:**

- Instance model brand "Iveco"
- Searching with 'Iveco' I obtain the right results
- Searching with "Iv" or "ec" no results.

**>>>>>> What's wrong?** why partial word search is ignored?

---

**Additional info**

I've found this, but not usefull: [link](http://elasticsearch.python.codesolution.site/1070271-9411-partial-word-search-haystack-elasticsearch.html)

> I think there's a bug in haystack in elasticsearch_backend.py which is
>   not using pyelasticsearch properly line 868 looks like:

```
self.conn.put_mapping('modelresult', current_mapping, index=self.index_name)
```

> And if you replace it by:

```
self.conn.put_mapping(doc_type='modelresult', mapping=current_mapping, index=self.index_name)
```

> which is how pyelasticsearch expects it, then you will see that the
>   edgengram_analyzer is added to your EdgeNgramField field. At least it
>   works for me.

---

**UPDATE**

**found this in elasticsearch logs**

```
[2016-04-15 09:01:36,164][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.mapping.put] [Eliminator] failed to put mappings on indices [[haystack]], type [modelresult]
MapperParsingException[Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_boost : {name=boost, null_value=1.0}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.checkNoRemainingFields(DocumentMapperParser.java:171)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:498)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:257)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:230)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:468)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:772)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2016-04-15 09:08:22,657][WARN ][http.netty               ] [Eliminator] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x5e3f8728, /127.0.0.1:51927 => /127.0.0.1:9200]
java.io.IOException: Connessione in corso interrotta forzatamente dall'host remoto
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: That's easy to check if you have access to ES and run a `curl` command directly on it, to check the actual mapping of the index.

Comment: got this: {"garagerr":{"mappings":{"modelresult":{"properties":{"brand":{"type":"string"},"chassis_number":{"type":"string"},"django_ct":{"type":"string"},"django_id":{"type":"string"},"garage":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"model":{"type":"string"},"plate_number":{"type":"string"},"text":{"type":"string"}}}}}}

Comment: The mapping setup didn't reach your index, you are not using edgeNGrams.

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look.